# invalid argument type 'void' to unary expression - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

code:

```
NSSpeechRecognizer *recog = [[NSSpeechRecognizer alloc]init];

NSArray *cmds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello",@"I'm back",nil];

[recog setCommands:cmds];

[recog startListening];

- (void)recog:(NSSpeechRecognizer *)sender didRecognizeCommand:(NSString *)cmds

if ([(NSString *)cmds isEqualToString:@"hello"]) {
    NSLog(@"Hello to you too");
}

if ([(NSString *)cmds isEqualToString:@"I'm back"]) {
    NSLog(@"Welcome back, its good to see you");
}
```

error message:

> invalid argument type 'void' to unary expression

Answer (score 0):

```
            Your Method Is Wrong (replace (nsstring*)to (id) and also not add clossing breckets.


- (void)recog:(NSSpeechRecognizer *)sender didRecognizeCommand:(id)cmds
{
               if ([(NSString *)cmds isEqualToString:@"hello"]) 
               {
                [self performSelector:@selector(hello:)];//also u can handle responce.
                NSLog(@"Hello to you too");
               }

            if ([(NSString *)cmds isEqualToString:@"I'm back"]) 
               {
                 NSLog(@"Welcome back, its good to see you");
               }
 }

-(void)hello:(id)sender 
  {
            //Do stuff here...

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare an instance method with `-` within a method.  It thinks you're trying to *negate* the method declaration with a negation operator, which is a unary operator.

Comment: Put the instance method where it belongs.